# JOINs inside of view included in join limit?

Tags: mysql, join

The query i'm writing requires joining dozens of tables. I'm receiving an error message - `"Error Code: 1116. Too many tables; MySQL can only use 61 tables in a join"` . If i create a number of views, splitting out the JOINs used in my main query between them, will I be able to use more than 61 JOINs? Or will the JOINs inside of each view be included in the 61 limit?

Comment: 61 tables? Why so many? Do you have a weird table design?

Comment: It's a very complicated schema, with around 150 tables. The query I'm writing is for a search function on a web application, and so i need to join around 100 tables.

Comment: How about writing a Stored Procedure and doing the joins in a few steps.

Comment: One hundred table in a single select... OMFG. Concerning the use of views, since it is executed dynamically I'm afraid it won't work neither, for the reason you pointed. Maybe it depends of the kind of motor and etc. But you can try and tell us ?